# Make a RPC from a client in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm wondering if I can make a RPC to meteor server from a client?

The context is that I like to get a list of files in server, something like the following:

```
// in server
var listdir = function() {
}

// in client
files = SERVER.listdir();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example code for calling server method: https://gist.github.com/2964422
Demo : http://servercall.meteor.com/
Meteor Documentation: http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header